# Same fragments in one TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I am trying to develop one activity, which contains TabLayout, which is build using one Fragment, but used a few times (same layout, different data). But when I have such a configuration, my app doesn't even go inside of getItem() method and doesn't show up my layout. Any ideas where is the problem?

My code:
Activity:

```
public class IndoorArenaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_arena);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    final PageAdapterArena adapter = new PageAdapterArena
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("today"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("tomorrow"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("13/11"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("14/11"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("15/11"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("16/11"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("17/11"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);


    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    // if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    //    return true;
    // }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class PageAdapterArena extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PageAdapterArena(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            fragment = IndoorArenaFragment.newInstance();
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class IndoorArenaFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.indoor_arena_fragment, container, false);
}

public static Fragment newInstance() {
    IndoorArenaFragment fragment = new IndoorArenaFragment();
    return fragment;
}
}
```

Layout for activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".IndoorArena.IndoorArenaActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />
```

Layout for fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="7:00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="Olga (Gatsby)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="8:00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="9:00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

App doesn't show up any errors, only the fragment looks like this:
[image]

And I would like to show up like this (each fragment):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually passing in `NumOfTabs` of `0` when you create the adapter, that's why you're getting an empty view in the `ViewPager`, and `getItem` not being called. To fix this, you just need to move your adapter creation line after adding the tabs:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("today"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("tomorrow"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("13/11"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("14/11"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("15/11"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("16/11"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("17/11"));
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

// Create adapter after adding the tabs
PageAdapterArena adapter = new PageAdapterArena(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I do that I get an error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setMenuVisibility(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:123)`

Comment: You need to fix your `getItem` in your adapter. Currently it's only returning fragment if requested position is 0, but null for other positions. Do not return null on `getItem`.